# How to Group and Sum List of Lists using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List of Lists that holds an *hourly* object.
I need to group all the lists into one, by grouping on the hour and summing the clicks and blocks.
I wrote the code using a for loop, but wonder how can I do it using a Linq.

```
    class hourly
    {
        public int clicks { get; set; }
        public int blocks { get; set; }
        public int hour { get; set; }

    }


       var m = new List<List<hourly>>();

     
     /// populate m from DB

   
        var n = new List<hourly>(24);

        for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
        {
            n.Add(new hourly());
            n[i] = new hourly() { hour = i, clicks = m.Sum(x => x[i].clicks), blocks = m.Sum(x => x[i].blocks) };
        }
```

Comment: I'm unsure of what you expect as an output... can you give an example? also, have you looked at the `GroupBy` LINQ method? Perhaps all you need to do is `var groups = n.GroupBy(h => h.hour);`

Comment: just a thought...if you get stack at this point, do a foreach instead of a for, then it is easier to move it to linq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you are looking for [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netcore-3.1) and [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1):

```
var result = m
    .SelectMany(ll => ll)
    .GroupBy(h => h.hour)
    .Select(g => new hourly
    {
        hour = g.Key,
        blocks = g.Sum(h => h.blocks),
        clicks = g.Sum(h => h.clicks)
    })
    .ToList();
```

If there are no instances of `hourly` in your db for some concrete hour and you need to have all in the final result you can add dummy ones after `SelectMany`, for example:

```
.Concat(Enumerable.Range(0, 24).Select(i => new hourly {hour = i}))
```

If ordering is important apply `OrderBy` before `ToList`.